# Transient json jax-rs

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am learning to create a rest api. Here is my `MessageResource` class:

```
@Path("/message")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public class MessageResource {

    private Map<Integer, Message> messages = Database.getMessages();

    @GET
    @Path("/all")
    public List<Message> allMessages() {
        return new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
    }

    //... some other stuff
}
```

`Message` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Message {

    private Integer id;
    private String message;
    private String author;

    public Message() {}

    public Message(Integer id, String message, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public boolean isValidToAdd() {
        if(Database.getMessages().containsKey(id) || id < 0) return false;
        if(message.isEmpty()) return false;
        if(author.isEmpty()) return false;
        return true;
    }

    //getters and setters for "id", "message" and "author"
}
```

The problem is that the response generated by `MessageResource.allMessages()` contains a field `validToAdd` when the `Accept` header is `application/json` but does not show when `Accept` header is `application/xml` or `text/xml`. I have tried adding `@XmlTransient` and `@JsonbTransient` to `Message.isValidToAdd()` but it still shows up. Any suggestion on how to remove `validToAdd` key from json response?

Comment: What JSON provider are you using?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha `jersey-media-json-binding`

Comment: Switch over to jersey-media-json-jackson.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

it's better to separate message validator into another class.
but if you want to have it in the message class you can consider a filed for it for example `public boolean validToAdd;`

now if you want to jsonb ignore it you can mark it as `@JsonbTransient public boolean validToAdd;` but xml binding does not ignore that and you can add `@XmlTransient` too.
or
make isValidToAdd a private method by that it can be only invoked from inside the class.

there is another way by playing with jsonb and create a custom setting for it(JsonbConfig).
**its better to separate messagevalidator as a class**

Comment: Creating a field `validToAdd` and annoting it with `JsonbTransient` worked but a new problem has arised. Now it shows when `Accept` header is `application/xml`. Is there any way I could get around without making a seperate validator class?